# Place id passed to Google direction service in result is differ then initall one why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I met a weird bug with gmap *DirectionsService*

When I'm drowning route through gmap direction service, by setting place_id as point identifier, after direction service process it in its response.geocoded_waypoints contain already different palce_id then i provided

Here is the code:

```
DIRECTIONS_SERVICE = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var waypoints = [
    { stopover: true, location: {'placeId': 'ChIJtXC0pYWWvUcRrwEu9-d8SBY'} }, 
    { stopover: true, location: {'placeId': 'EjJCaW5nZXIgU3RyLiAyMjksIDU1MjE4IEluZ2VsaGVpbSBhbSBSaGVpbiwgR2VybWFueSIbEhkKFAoSCbnrxjVv7L1HEVNz9RmnN4aOEOUB'} }
];

DIRECTIONS_SERVICE.route({
    origin: { 'placeId': 'ChIJbZbhjI2zuEcRLLLb2BkH9qE' },
    destination: { 'placeId': 'ChIJbZbhjI2zuEcRLLLb2BkH9qE' },
    waypoints: waypoints,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
}, function(response, status) {

    if (status === 'OK') {

        DIRECTIONS_RENDER.setDirections(response);
        DIRECTIONS_RENDER_RESPONSE = response;

        // HERE above provide waypoint  
        // place id: EjJCaW5nZXIgU3RyLiAyMjksIDU1MjE4IEluZ2VsaGVpbSBhbSBSaGVpbiwgR2VybWFueSIbEhkKFAoSCbnrxjVv7L1HEVNz9RmnN4aOEOUB 
        // already changed to EitMNDE5IDIyOSwgNTUyMTggSW5nZWxoZWltIGFtIFJoZWluLCBHZXJtYW55IhsSGQoUChIJuevGNW_svUcRU3P1Gac3ho4Q5QE
        console.log(DIRECTIONS_RENDER_RESPONSE.geocoded_waypoints);

    } else {
        window.alert('Problem in showing direction due to ' + status);
    }
});
```

Is this a bug or normal behaver ? it is not clear for me why gmap change by place id ?

Comment: A "place" can have multiple placeIds; but a placeId will only ever point to a single place. So as long as both placeIds are the same "place" this is allowed.

Comment: @geocodezip The thing is later i loop over responce.geocoded_waypoints and compere its place id with my array place id to understand e.g. point B is my initial this address to do some logic but this place id change makes its impossible...

Comment: Even route.legs item contain already different latitude longitude, so seems gmap change my provided place id to another place with another lat,lng and place id where car can enter

Answer (score 0):

Wooh, spend on this 2 days ...

i solved this so that instead passing to waypoints as location place id

```
// Instead this
var waypoints = [
    { stopover: true, location: {'placeId': 'ChIJtXC0pYWWvUcRrwEu9-d8SBY'} }, 
    { stopover: true, location: {'placeId': 'EjJCaW5nZXIgU3RyLiAyMjksIDU1MjE4IEluZ2VsaGVpbSBhbSBSaGVpbiwgR2VybWFueSIbEhkKFAoSCbnrxjVv7L1HEVNz9RmnN4aOEOUB'} }
];

// Need to use
var waypoints = [
    { stopover: true, location: 'address 1' }, 
    { stopover: true, location: 'address 2' }
];
```

**in this case in result of direction service place id matches initial place id, or evan compareing inital adress  =  to direction response driving address**

NOTE: I'm almost sure this is some bug, case during my debug i sow that address is changed
e.g. initial address is "Bingerstrasse 229, 55218 Ingelheim" in direction response.legs  dump address is already "Bingerstrasse 301, 55218 Ingelheim" so address is totally different ...